# HTML Columns in the middle of the screen

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns

This may be a basic html + css question but it's being kinda thought for me to solve :S

You see, I need a '3 column' layout. I want a central column (let's say 10em width) and two more columns one at each side (let's say 2em width each). I want the three in the middle of the screen...

How can I do it by declaring each of them separately? I mean, do something like this:

```
<div class="left"><!-- 2em width --></div>
<div class="central"><!-- 10em width --></div>
<div class="right"><!-- 2em width --></div>
```

Is there some way to do it without evolving them in another container?

Thx!

Comment: So... you can't put them in a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was looking for a similar solution, this helped me immensely: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Comment: There is some overlap. The link provides a more comprehensive solution (and overview of the underlying design pattern). It helped me a lot when I was first starting out, so, hopefully googol can benefit as well!

Comment: Though if I was googol I would probably just read the link I provided, then implement your code :) It's leaner

Comment: Ok, thx for all the answers. The thing is that i was looking for some way to do it without evolving them in any other container. I wanted them to be independent.
I had already tried that solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of giving them a percent-width?

```
.left {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 10%;
}
.central {
    width: 50%;
}
.right {
    width: 10%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
div { float: left; height: 100%; }
body { height: 1000px;}
```

Because 15+10+50+10+15 = 100.

I even added a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VjbFz/

I still think wrapping them in a container is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="left"><!-- 2em width --></div>
        <div class="central"><!-- 10em width --></div>
        <div class="right"><!-- 2em width --></div>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    text-align: center;    
}

.cleaner { clear: both; }

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 14em;
    text-align: left;
}   

.left { width: 2em; float: left; }
.central { width: 10em; float: left; }
.right { width: 2em; float: left; }​
```

.cleaner is here just because of floats.

I also added it on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmzWr/

I hope that it'd be helpful :)